# Where are methods in java.awt.Graphics defined?

Tags: java, graphics

I've been thinking a lot about making my own Java3D API for a few projects of mine. (Yes, I've seen the Java3D API provided by Oracle.) Many methods in java.awt.Graphics are defined, such as drawRect(), however some basic functions, such as drawLine(), are abstract. How is it possible to create a Graphics object (as in the code below) when there is no implementation in Graphics.java?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Hello World!");
}
```

Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are natively implemented by the JRE. BTW, the example does not really illustrate your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implementation-specific, but these methods are usually implemented natively so that they can interface directly with the native windowing system.  You cannot instantiate a `Graphics` object because the concrete implementation of `Graphics` that you would want to use is probably an implementation-specific subtype of `Graphics` that interacts with the native system.  Forcing the Java libraries and JVM implementers to create this object for you prevents you from having to deal with the nastiness of OS-level details and provides a generic, type-safe interface to the graphics package.

If you want to implement your own package, you would probably have to use JNI to implement a graphics package.  You could then implement the graphics on top of OpenGL, DirectX, or whatever other system that you'd like.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**[copied from my comment:]** These are natively implemented by the JRE.

You can create a buffered image, and get a graphics objects for it:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = image.getGraphics();
```

See also: http://www.coderanch.com/t/345202/GUI/java/Create-Graphics-object

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The OP's question is how `Graphics` is created when many of the methods are abstract, not how to get a handle to an existing `Graphics` object.

Comment: It answers the question 'How is it possible to create a Graphics object (as in the code below) when `true`?' but you are always welcome to downvote my answer.